# Scapy - How to Dissect an Ethernet Trailer field

Tags: python, network-programming, ethernet, scapy, f5

I'm using the F5 Networks Big-IP products, which are appending a custom Ethernet II trailer frame for debugging purposes. I'm trying with Scapy to bind a new layer for this trailer, but I'm unable to do so.

I can see the payload of interest in the Padding field but using bind_layers does not perform proper dissection of the required Padding section.

```
class MyEthTrailer(Packet):
    name = "Ethernet Trailer"
    fields_desc = [ ####Fields Mapping Section ]
    def dissect(self, s):
        self.payl,self.pad = self.extract_padding(s)
        s = self.do_dissect(self.pad)
```

One solution I was thinking was to create a new Ethernet replacement class (or overloaded), which I can then refers to the typical Ethernet payload and my new trailer. But I'm not a super Python/scapy programmer, and I am not certain if this is the best option.

This is how Scapy currently maps my packet  after I apply bind_layers(TCP,MyEthTrailer). The info I should have parse is in the Padding class

```
<Ether  dst=00:00:00:00:00:00 src=00:00:00:00:00:01 type=0x8100 |<Dot1Q  prio=0L id=0L vlan=01L type=0x800 |<IP  version=4L ihl=5L tos=0x0 len=67 id=1 flags=DF frag=0L ttl=255 proto=tcp chksum=0x01 src=10.0.0.1 dst=10.0.1.1 options=[] |<TCP  sport=1111 dport=https seq=1 ack=1 dataofs=5L reserved=0L flags=PA window=4380 chksum=0xb718 urgptr=0 options=[] |<MyEthTrailer  |<Padding  load='\xPayload of MyEtherTrailer' |>>>>>>
```

[UPDATE-1]

I can force decoding a TCP SYN packet by calling :

```
packet[TCP].decode_payload_as(MyEthTrailer)
```

However, the bind_layers method, does not seem to work automatically, and this does not work with more complex packet because it's mixing up TCP Padding with MyEthTrailer payload.

[UPDATE-2]

I got it partly working, but every packet needs to be casted properly, then I can read the trailer payload and decode it. For example if a packet is TCP/DNS/MyEthTrailer, this will work. If I don't know it's DNS, and it's not set up properly, it's still mixed in in TCP payload and Padding.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: The F5 plugin source is here: https://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/AdvDesignConfig.F5WiresharkPlugin.ashx. Hopefully this will help you isolate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it by overloading the pre_dissect function of my new custom class MyEthTrailer. I try to parse the payload of the last layer which has Padding, and verify if it has the correct length.

This is handle with 2 things :

PART 1 DISSECT section

```
class MyEthTrailer(Packet):
    def pre_dissect(self,s):
        verify_if_payload_is_mine_and_assign_fields()
```

PART 2  Manual Force payload decode

```
_debug=True

if re.match(r'F5\-Pseudo-\pkt.+tcpdump',str(packets[0][Raw])):
        if re.match(r'.+CMD\:.+\-s0.+VER\:.+',str(packets[0][Raw])): has_F5_trailer=True
        if re.match(r'.+CMD\:.+\:nnn.+VER\:.+',str(packets[0][Raw])): F5_trailer_noise_level=3
        elif re.match(r'.+CMD\:.+\:nn.+VER\:.+',str(packets[0][Raw])): F5_trailer_noise_level=2
        elif re.match(r'.+CMD\:.+\:n.+VER\:.+',str(packets[0][Raw])): F5_trailer_noise_level=1
        else:
            if _debug: print "No F5 EthTrailer F5_Noise_level visible from packets[0]"
    if has_F5_trailer:
        #Skip the F5 first packet, which only contains the info. 
        for pk in packets[1:]:
            try:
                if isinstance(pk.lastlayer(),Padding):
                    pk.lastlayer().underlayer.decode_payload_as(MyEthTrailer)
            except:
                #Errorhandling
```

I will post the whole solution to Github and update here if anybody is interested.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing a GitHub link please - as I am having an issue forcing a custom layer to be decoded. I am just trying you packet[TCP].decode_payload_as(MyEthTrailer) implementation.